# Problema al concatenar una variable laravel dentro de un for

Tags: php, laravel

Hola chicos tengo un bucle el cual necesito recoger varios **checkbox** por el método request de laravel, la cosa es que necesito concatenar el nombre del request del checkbox con la cuenta del for, el motivo es que necesito saber solo cuales están marcados y cuales no para poder ir metiendo los dentro de un array.

CheckBox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckboxProducto{{$dato->id}}" onclick="checkBox()" name="myCheckboxProducto{{$dato->id}}" />
```

Funcion Controller

```
for($i=1; $i<100; $i++){   

    $myCheckboxProducto=$request->myCheckboxProducto.$i;



    if( $myCheckboxProducto!="")
    {

        $array[] = $myCheckboxProducto;
    }
}

return $array;
```

**PD:** si yo cambio el numero del contador por el número real de un checkbox si que me sale como que esta "ON" pero mediante el contador me es imposible y no se en lo que estoy errando.

```
$myCheckboxProducto=$request->myCheckboxProducto1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones para dar solución
1. Utilizar la funcion `get` de request concatenando a un string

```
$request->get("myCheckboxProducto$i");
```

2. Utilizar llaves para modificar un parametro del objeto request

```
$request->{"myCheckboxProducto$i"}
```

Comment: Fenómeno! ha funcionado correctamente!

Answer (score 3):

También puede usar el metodo input de tu variable $request:

```
for($i=1; $i<100; $i++){ 
    $myCheckboxProducto = $request->input('myCheckboxProducto' . $i);

    if( $myCheckboxProducto != "") {
        $array[] = $myCheckboxProducto;
    }
}
```